# How to Abbreviate Number of Fields in RPART

Tags: r

Please take a look at the following RPART code in R:

```
fit<-rpart(SCR_ADULT_SILVER ~
  HCC1+HCC2+HCC3+HCC4+HCC5+HCC6+HCC7+HCC8+HCC9+HCC10+HCC11+HCC12+HCC13+HCC14+HCC15+HCC16+
  HCC17+HCC18+HCC19+HCC20+HCC21+HCC22+HCC23+HCC24+HCC25+HCC26+HCC27+HCC28+HCC29+HCC30+HCC31,
  method="anova",
  control=rpart.control(minsplit=210,cp=0.001,usesurrogate=0),
  data=Adult)
```

How may I specify all of the variables that begin with HCC are my variables of interest without spelling all of them out?

Answer (score 0):

One option is `reformulate`

```
rpart(reformulate(names(Adult)[startsWith(names(Adult), "HCC")], 
          "SCR_ADULT_SILVER"), 
      method="anova",
    control=rpart.control(minsplit=210,cp=0.001,usesurrogate=0),
      data=Adult)
```

Or another option is `subset` the data columns and specify the `~ .`

```
rpart(SCR_ADULT_SILVER ~ ., method="anova",
    control=rpart.control(minsplit=210,cp=0.001,usesurrogate=0),
     data = Adult[c("SCR_ADULT_SILVER", grep("^HCC\\d+$", names(Adult),
           value = TRUE))])
```

---

As an example

```
v1 <- c("HCC1", "HCC5", "XYZ")
reformulate(v1[startsWith(v1, "HCC")], "SCR_ADULT_SILVER")
#SCR_ADULT_SILVER ~ HCC1 + HCC5
```